# Uncaught java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: java, sockets, exception, nio

With Java 1.7, the following code

```
try
{
  sck = SocketChannel.open();
  sck.configureBlocking(false);

  sck.connect(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(**<bad remote ip address>**, remote_port));
  sel = Selector.open();

  ...
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  return false;
}
```

doesn't seem to catch the exception if the remote address is a bad DNS (for instance). What did I miss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UnresolvedAddressException` is *not* a subclass of `IOException`, which is why you won't catch it if it's thrown.

`UnresolvedAddressException` is a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException`, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/UnresolvedAddressException.html), so try catching:

- `UnresolvedAddressException` itself, as it's always better practice to catch the most specific exception type first
- `Exception` if you don't really care about the exception you catch, as you can always halt the program or work around that

**Edit**: You probably missed that exception because the compiler did not force you to catch it. That is because `UnresolvedAddressException` is derived from `RuntimeException`, the type of exceptions which smack you in the head *during execution*. The exceptions *not* derived from `RuntimeException`, such as `IOException`, *have to be caught*, which is why your compiler probably told you to wrap your code into a try-catch block in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

UnresolvedAddressException is not a child of IOException.
UnresolvedAddressException extends RuntimeException.
You can try to add catch closure with RuntimeException.